# Able to see all the projects in Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse

I have multiple projects in eclipse but i want to see only one project at a time(don't want to see the project which are closed rite now).How can it be achieved in eclipse's Project Explorer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter closed project. [Check here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-48b.htm). In filter tab choose `closed projects`.

Also you can use [mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn) plug-in to show only relevant resources in views and editors.

Comment: Doing it this way has problem,if suppose i have 10 projects but i am working on 1 project other 9 are closed.Then it will be difficult to choose there name.Is there a way, where i can see the project name and when i click on that  it will open that project on Project Explorer.

Comment: Choosing the project name is not required. If you select `closed projects` option all 9 closed projects will be hidden. Try mylyn plugin it shows the active project/resources in the project explorer [Check here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/User_Guide#Focusing_Navigator_Views)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer,So thought of sharing it with you all.

Go to Windows>Show Views > package Explorer

Now select the project you want to give a name and right click on it.

Now select Assign Working sets > then New > opt for java > then give a valid name

and done.

Now you can select the project by that name;No other project will be displayed with it.If you want t o open that project go to menu of package explorer and select the project.

Clean and crisp